# Hiding the removal of intermediate files using Make

Tags: recursion, build, makefile, temporary-files

I use intermediate files in my Makefile, however make prints out the rm command that it uses to delete them all afterwards. How do I hide this print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) says that targets marked `.SECONDARY` will behave as `.INTERMEDIATE` but won't be automatically deleted. You could mark all the intermediate targets as secondary, and then remove the files yourself, something like

```
OBJECTS=foo.o bar.o
all:foo bar
    @rm -f $(OBJECTS)
.SECONDARY: $(OBJECTS)
```

should do.

Comment: That does do the job, so I'll accept it, but this is a bit of a hack in my opinion, I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: It does the job, but you'd have to add that `rm` command on all targets if you want it to be as universal as `.INTERMEDIATE` :-(